# Postgres plpgsql Increase Speed of INSERT INTO... statement from CTE, using COPY ( TO || FROM)

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to move millions of records from one table to another table (archive). I am able dropping all the FK and indexes before doing this INSERT. Basically, I am using a `LOOP` and creating a **CTE** inside that I later use to `INSERT INTO...` my **archive** table. It works because each time I iterate, I am getting new data in my CTE i.e.

```
do
$$
declare
begin
  loop
   exit when rec_count = 0;
   
   WITH some_cte AS (
       select * 
       from some_table st
       where not exists (select 1 from some_archive_table sat where sat.id = st.id)
       limit 10000
   ),
   INSERT INTO some_archive_table (select * from some_cte);

   get diagnostics rec_count = row_count;
 end loop;
end;
$$
```

I saw on stackoverflow people were recommending the `COPY` command, but it looks like I have to read from a file or stdin and I can't read from a table and copy to a table.

Would it actually be faster to output the data as CSV and then read it back in from the CSV to the table?

I was trying this now , but was getting the error

```
ERROR: must be superuser or a member of the pg_write_server_files role to COPY to a file
HINT: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

Is it worth trying to fix this access issue, or could I output it to STDOUT/STDIN or will I not see improvements with COPY vs INSERT? I would like any help possible!

Comment: Do you have a unique index on sat.id? If yes you could simply use `insert on conflict (id) do nothing` and get rid of the `where not exists` condition -  most probably that would be faster

Comment: Also, why the `CTE`? You could just include the `select *  from some_table st ...` query as the `SELECT` portion of `INSERT INTO some_archive_table ...`

Comment: You also need to add `rec_count integer;` to the `DECLARE`.